How can I change the client side User Agent String of a WebView page?
I'm trying to authenticate on a website that only works on Linux. In a standard browser window this can easily be done with an extension that changes the User Agent String (for example, User-Agent Switcher for Chrome
However when authenticating through applications, (for example Mozilla Thunderbird authentication when adding a new email or calendar account), it uses a WebView window instead of a full browser.
This WebView does not have any extensions or any developer tools.
Is there ANY way to change the User Agent String for a web-view window? For example to specify the Linux User Agent instead of Windows?
